# I have opened .xcworkspace and when run application am getting clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c

duplicate symbol _GTMNSDictionaryURLArgumentsExportToSuppressLibToolWarning in:
    /Users/Varshana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodore-axtsfmjdyxbqyccujoquacrynsxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.o)
    /Users/Varshana/Documents/Lodore final stage/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments_aec9c2446af4c2ac5a7380b418b337ea.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2WebViewKey in:
    /Users/Varshana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodore-axtsfmjdyxbqyccujoquacrynsxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2/libGTMOAuth2.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
    /Users/Varshana/Documents/Lodore final stage/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2Authentication_ad53759ab562393658e6c193e56628dd.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMOAuth2ErrorRequestKey in:
    /Users/Varshana/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodore-axtsfmjdyxbqyccujoquacrynsxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMOAuth2/libGTMOAuth2.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
    /Users/Varshana/Documents/Lodore final stage/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMOAuth2Authentication_ad53759ab562393658e6c193e56628dd.o)

Answer (score 0):

don't worry, just xcode bug. try clean and build and it will work, or better, go to xcode->preferences->location->Derived Data. delete all files inside derived data and then restart xcode. clean and build the project and then it will work perfectly

ps: updated for cleaning
Cmd + Shift + Alt + K

To check the exact error for this issue check following:

Select issue navigator > Click on error will show logs for error > In that select All Messages tab.

```
75 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Means that you have loaded same functions twice. As the issue disappear after removing  -ObjC from Other Linker Flags, this means that this option result that functions loads twice:

from Technical Q&A

```
This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library 
that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will 
typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code 
loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of 
effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on 
existing classes.
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: I have done clean and build but its not working , again same error is hoping up and in derived data there are no files.

Comment: there are no chances that derived data to be empty, check it carefully

Comment: I have deleted all the files from derived data , now there is only 2 files (ModuleCache and some other file related to my project), but still same error is poping up

Comment: once i used to have the same problem, but my problem was that my files weren't anymore in my workspace, theyn were uploaded in icloud automaticlly. Check it once, just to be sure

Comment: can you make a screen shoot of the message?

Comment: i have edited my answer. check there the solution. you problem is that you that you have loaded same functions twice.

Comment: your problem is at googleSignIn. check where you use it

Comment: $(inherited) -l"GTMOAuth2" -l"GTMSessionFetcher" -l"GoogleToolboxForMac" -l"c++" -l"sqlite3" -l"stdc++" -l"z" -framework "AddressBook" -framework "AssetsLibrary" -framework "CoreFoundation" -framework "CoreLocation" -framework "CoreMotion" -framework "CoreText" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseInstanceID" -framework "GGLCore" -framework "GGLSignIn" -framework "GoogleSignIn" -framework "MessageUI" -framework "SafariServices" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration"

Comment: Targets > Build Phases > Compile Sources and delete any duplicate files.

Comment: also check the pod file where you have installed Google

Comment: problem stands for gitokenfetchdelegate